# PostgreSQL tree structure and recursive CTE optimization

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, cte, tree

I'm trying to represent a tree structure in PostgreSQL (8.4) to be able to query the path from the root to a given node or to find all the nodes within a sub-branch.

Here is a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE tree_data_1 (
    forest_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    node_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    parent_id TEXT,
    node_type TEXT,
    description TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (forest_id, node_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (forest_id, parent_id) REFERENCES tree_data_1 (forest_id, node_id)
);
CREATE INDEX tree_data_1_forestid_parent_idx ON tree_data_1(forest_id, parent_id);
CREATE INDEX tree_data_1_forestid_idx ON tree_data_1(forest_id);
CREATE INDEX tree_data_1_nodeid_idx ON tree_data_1(node_id);
CREATE INDEX tree_data_1_parent_idx ON tree_data_1(parent_id);
```

Each node is identified by `(forest_id, node_id)` (there can be another node with the same name in another forest). Each tree starts at a root node (where `parent_id` is null), although I'm only expecting one per forest.

Here is the view that uses a recursive CTE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tree_view_1 AS
    WITH RECURSIVE rec_sub_tree(forest_id, node_id, parent_id, depth, path, cycle) AS (
        SELECT td.forest_id, td.node_id, td.parent_id, 0, ARRAY[td.node_id], FALSE FROM tree_data_1 td
        UNION ALL
        SELECT td.forest_id, rec.node_id, td.parent_id, rec.depth+1, td.node_id || rec.path, td.node_id = ANY(rec.path)
            FROM tree_data_1 td, rec_sub_tree rec
            WHERE td.forest_id = rec.forest_id AND rec.parent_id = td.node_id AND NOT cycle
     )
     SELECT forest_id, node_id, parent_id, depth, path
         FROM rec_sub_tree;
```

This is a slightly modified version of the [example in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html), to take into account the `forest_id`, and that returns `rec.node_id` in the recursive `SELECT` instead of what would be `td.node_id`.

The get the path from the root to a given node, this query can be used:

```
SELECT * FROM tree_view_1 WHERE forest_id='Forest A' AND node_id='...' AND parent_id IS NULL
```

The get a sub-tree, this query can be used:

```
SELECT * FROM tree_view_1 WHERE forest_id='Forest A' AND parent_id='...'
```

The get a full tree within a given forest:

```
SELECT * FROM tree_view_1 WHERE forest_id='Forest A' AND parent_id IS NULL
```

The last query uses the following query plan (viewable on [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/NTD6)):

```
 CTE Scan on rec_sub_tree  (cost=1465505.41..1472461.19 rows=8 width=132) (actual time=0.067..62480.876 rows=133495 loops=1)
   Filter: ((parent_id IS NULL) AND (forest_id = 'Forest A'::text))
   CTE rec_sub_tree
     ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..1465505.41 rows=309146 width=150) (actual time=0.048..53736.585 rows=1645992 loops=1)
           ->  Seq Scan on tree_data_1 td  (cost=0.00..6006.16 rows=247316 width=82) (actual time=0.034..975.796 rows=247316 loops=1)
           ->  Hash Join  (cost=13097.90..145331.63 rows=6183 width=150) (actual time=2087.065..5842.870 rows=199811 loops=7)
                 Hash Cond: ((rec.forest_id = td.forest_id) AND (rec.parent_id = td.node_id))
                 ->  WorkTable Scan on rec_sub_tree rec  (cost=0.00..49463.20 rows=1236580 width=132) (actual time=0.017..915.814 rows=235142 loops=7)
                       Filter: (NOT cycle)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=6006.16..6006.16 rows=247316 width=82) (actual time=1871.964..1871.964 rows=247316 loops=7)
                       ->  Seq Scan on tree_data_1 td  (cost=0.00..6006.16 rows=247316 width=82) (actual time=0.017..872.725 rows=247316 loops=7)
 Total runtime: 62978.883 ms
(12 rows)
```

As expected, this isn't very efficient. I'm partly surprised it doesn't seem to make use of any index.

Considering that this data would be read often but rarely modified (perhaps a small modification every couple of weeks), what possible techniques are there to optimise such queries and/or data representation?

**EDIT:** I would also like to retrieve the tree in depth-first order. Using `ORDER BY path` also degrades substantially the speed of the query above.

---

Sample Python program to populate the table with test data (requires [Psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/)), probably a bit more than I expect to have in a more realistic situation:

```
from uuid import uuid4
import random
import psycopg2

random.seed(1234567890)
min_depth = 3
max_depth = 6
max_sub_width = 10
next_level_prob = 0.7

db_connection = psycopg2.connect(database='...')
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO tree_data_1(forest_id, node_id, parent_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

def generate_sub_tree(forest_id, parent_id=None, depth=0, node_ids=[]):
    if not node_ids:
        node_ids = [ str(uuid4()) for _ in range(random.randint(1, max_sub_width)) ]
    for node_id in node_ids:
        cursor.execute(query, [ forest_id, node_id, parent_id ])
        if depth < min_depth or (depth < max_depth and random.random() < next_level_prob):
            generate_sub_tree(forest_id, node_id, depth+1)

generate_sub_tree('Forest A', node_ids=['Node %d' % (i,) for i in range(10)])
generate_sub_tree('Forest B', node_ids=['Node %d' % (i,) for i in range(10)])

db_connection.commit()
db_connection.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have to modify these data rarely, then you can simply store the result of the CTE in a table, and run queries against this table.  You can define indexes based on your typical queries.
Then `TRUNCATE` and repopulate (and `ANALYZE`) as necessary.

On the other hand, if you can put the CTE in separate stored procedures rather than a view, you can easily put your conditions in the CTE part rather then the final `SELECT` (which is basically what you do querying against `tree_view_1`), so that much less rows will be involved in the recursion.  From the query plan it looks like that PostgreSQL estimates row numbers based on some far-from-true assumptions, probably producing suboptimal plans - this effect can be reduced somewhat with the SP solution.

**EDIT** I may miss something, but just noticed that in the non-recursive term you don't filter the rows.  Possibly you want to include only root nodes there (`WHERE parent_id IS NULL`) - I'd expect much less rows and recursions this way.

**EDIT 2**  AS it slowly became clear for me from the comments, I misthought the recursion in the original question going the other way.  Here I mean starting from the root nodes and going deeper in the recursion.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what you mean by putting `WHERE parent_id IS NULL` in the non-recursive term (or generally filtering there): this prevents the recursion from happening.

Comment: Why would it prevent recursion?  The non-recursive term just sets the 'anchor' for starting the recursion.  So first you collect all your root nodes and then go through all the forests starting from there.

Comment: If I do this query without a view (directly `WITH RECURSIVE ...`) and use `SELECT td.forest_id, td.node_id, td.parent_id, 0, ARRAY[td.node_id], FALSE FROM tree_data_1 td WHERE parent_id IS NULL`, only the root nodes (where parent_id is null) are returned by the overall query. The other nodes are not taken into account (that's what I would expect).

Comment: Hm.  Hmm.  I think I see what I've missed: you state `rec.parent_id = td.node_id` there.  But if the non-recursive term collects the root nodes then `td.parent_id = rec.node_id` is the condition of the next level.  Isn't this what you wanted to mean?  (I think not, you started the other way round...)

Comment: Ah, I see where you're getting at. If I change completely the order of the recursion (putting the `WHERE parent_id IS NULL` in the non-recursive term, selecting `td.node_id` instead of `rec.node_id` and using `td.parent_id = rec.node_id` in the recursive term), I do get the expected results faster indeed!